# Wine and mono application install

Tags: linux, wine

I intend to install a application, namely the game "Lineage II", on Linux through Wine, but the terminal log are below:

```
00d5:fixme:mscoree:parse_startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=L"true" not implemented
00d5:fixme:mscoree:get_runtime_info unsupported startup flags 2
00d5:err:mscoree:RuntimeHost_Invoke Method System.AppDomain:CreateDomain raised an exception, hr=80131515
00d5:fixme:mscoree:corruntimehost_Stop stub 0x159e60
00d5:err:mscoree:expect_no_runtimes Process exited with a Mono runtime loaded.
```

If necessary, I can provide more information about it.
Best regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `mscoree:expect_no_runtimes` is thrown when mono is missing some critical interface. See [here](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46043) for an example and a fix.

Installing native dotnet20 (or whatever version that game uses) is usually enough to solve such kinds of error. Otherwise there's not much you can do other than pointing out this bug to the wine devs (if they haven't fix it already in the meantime), or trying to work around the installer with external tools.